# Solving Coupled Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm having trouble solving these coupled partial differential equations:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t) }{\partial t^2}=0 ,$$

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f(x,t)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t) }{\partial x \partial t } =0 $$

I want to solve this system of PDE using numerical methods. I know how to solve PDEs with one dependent variable using the finite difference method. However, here we have two dependent variables and I am unaware of any numerical methods that can be used to solve this. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Finite difference method is applicable here too. Use it to discretize derivatives. Now you just need to compute two fields $u^{n+1}, f^{n+1}$ instead of one after each time step.
Anyway, finite difference method may lead to different approximations. Depending on them the time stepping algorithm may be different. For example, explicit schemes are super easy to implement whatever number of variables you have. In constrast, implicit methods become trickier when the number of variables increases. Please add details on how you would like to approximate the equations to get a better advice.

Comment: @uranix Is the finite difference method sensible when there are second derivatives w.r.t $t$? Indeed I can see no grounds on which to distinguish either variable as "time" in these equations (except of course that one has the name $t$!)

Comment: Fun fact: there is no Lagrangian of the form $L\left(x,t,u,f,u_{x},u_{t},f_{x},f_{t}\right)$ for this system.

Comment: @Ali There's no problem with second derivatives w.r.t. time. For example a common way to approximate wave equation $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx} + f$ would be
$$
\frac{u^{n+1}_m - 2u^n_m + u^{n-1}_m}{\Delta t^2} = c^2 
\frac{u^n_{m+1} - 2u^n_m + u^n_{m-1}}{\Delta x^2} + f^n_m.
$$
This is an explicit scheme (one can easily solve it for $u^{n+1}_m$).

Comment: @uranix Hmm ok I guess you need initial value and first derivative for that. Perhaps I was getting confused; thinking more about boundary conditions than about order.

Comment: What ICs/BCs do you have?